# Xcode Data Model Compiler - MOMC Error: Command momc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcdatamodel

I am having troubles integrating XMPP on my iOS Project using Xcode 4.4 under Mac Mountain Lion OS X. I followed every step but I got stuck with this problem:

> Command momc failed with exit code 1

See screenshot:
[image]

I have deleted all the .xcdatamodel files, clean and re-build the project, but the error is still there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok. Solved it. You have to delete the *.xcdatamodel files on the Xcode project. (Right click > Delete).

Comment: Same. I deleted the .xcdatamodel file and reimported.

Comment: I had this after moving the file to a different directory. No amount of deleting derived data/clean builds would fix it - I had to delete it from the project, clean everything and then re-add it.

Comment: Follow-up: it still came back a few builds later. I had to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25686846/337392

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have empty .xcdatamodel folders inside .xcdatamodeld. This may happen due to git behaviour for example.

Comment: For me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is iOS/iOS Simulator version!
If you don't delete the *.xcdatamodel for git, you can try replace iOS/iOS Simulator SDK or update.
My problem is resolved in this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Face the same problem

I just created new model with new name and copy all the entity from old model and paste in new model and deleted old model, it worked

Answer (score 0):

This also can happen when the project is first compiled on a newer version of xCode (beta versions for example) and then trying to recompile with the original version.